# Java send PublicKey to PHP and encrypt data

Tags: java, php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

So I have a PublicKey in Java, and I need to send a post request to the server with the key in it, then read the key server side, and send some data encrypted with it!

I succeeded at:

- Generating the keypair (duh)
- Encrypting and decrypting data with it in the Java program
- Maybe: making a pem formatted key from it, I'm not sure

```
String phpPublic = ("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"+Base64.encodeToString(MainActivity.instance.rsa.readPublicKeyFromFile(MainActivity.instance.rsa.PUBLIC_CLIENT_KEY_FILE).getEncoded(),Base64.DEFAULT)+"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----");
```

I think this does it, but I'm not sure! And would it be the same process to convert private keys to pem, just to make PUBLIC -> PRIVATE in the header and footer.

I don't know if converting to pem is really necessary, if it's not, please suggest a better way to do it.

This is how I do it in PHP, but I'm 99% sure it is wrong

```
$PubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($publicPem);
$encrypted;
openssl_public_encrypt($toEncode, $encrypted, $PubKey);
echo $encrypted;
```

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried running that code? Did you get wrong result or an error?

Comment: It says that the object is not a key

Answer (score 1):

can you post a sample key?

in lieu of that i do think you'd have better success with [phpseclib a pure php rsa implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). it supports a lot more key formats than openssl does and it'll auto detect the type too.

example:

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('...');

$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
echo $rsa->encrypt('whatever');
```